# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected element type 'IndexPath' error

Tags: swift, uitableview

I keep getting the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected element type
>   'IndexPath'

On line `self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)`

**Code:**

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row
        myModels[selectedIndexPath].isSelected = true
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)

    }
```

How can this be improved?

Comment: Read the documentation for `reloadRows` and note the expected data types of the parameters. Then look at the data types you are actually providing.

Answer (score 0):

So `reloadRows(at:` requires an array with `IndexPath` inside of them as the first parameter ie: `[IndexPath]`. You took the `row` of an `IndexPath` which is an `Int` and put that in an array ie: `[Int]`.

To me it looks likes you are just trying to reload the cell selected so you should **replace this**:

```
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
```

**with this**:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```

so your whole didSelectRowAtIndexPath function should look like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row
    myModels[selectedIndexPath].isSelected = true
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)

}
```

Comment: It's also good practice to make use of the provided `tableView` parameter. The last line should drop `self.`. This avoids issues if there is ever more than one table view being handled by the data source/delegate method.

Comment: You're right. I just put the answer in the context of what he included in his question. I'll edit.

Comment: However, if you have multiple tableviews you would want to probably check which tableview it is before you blindly execute code (ie: if tableView == self.tableView { //then do something }) I suspect he probably does not have multiple tableviews.